# How to save this Excel sheet as Text File (.txt) in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to upload an excel sheet and save it as text file and then read from that text file. One of my friends implemented like this in his application and it is working fine. I just copied his code but it did not work with me properly. It saved the excel sheet as a text file but when I opened the text file, I found the data corrupted and a lot of Unicode or strange symbols with many unnecessary lines such as:

> ```
>           ;          þÿÿÿ    þÿÿÿ    :
> ```
>
> ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

**ASP.NET code:**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btn_upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
```

**C# code:**

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Upload.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                Upload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Test_" + DateTime.Now.Year + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + ".txt"));
                LabelUpload.Text = "Upload File Name: " + Upload.PostedFile.FileName + "<br>" + "Type: " + Upload.PostedFile.ContentType + " File Size: " + Upload.PostedFile.ContentLength + " kb<br>";

                string filename = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Test_" + DateTime.Now.Year + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + ".txt");
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    LabelUpload.Text = LabelUpload.Text + "Uploaded Successfully";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            LabelUpload.Text = "Please select a file to upload.";

        }
    }
```

I am using ASP.NET 4 with C#, so **could you please tell me what I should to be able to save the Excel sheet as a txt file and then read from it?**

Comment: The same thing happens when you take an Excel document and change the extension to txt. You need an extension that is actually able to open/read Office documents, and then parse the contents to simple text. In any case, the final implementation will need to be much more sophisticated than what you have here.

Comment: Note the answers, but don't implement them using Office Interop. It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 5):

In order for an Excel file to be readable in a text editor, it has to be converted to the CSV file format.  This is because .xlsx Excel documents (2007+) are complex XML hierarchies.  If you are curious to see what really makes up a .xlsx file, change its extension to .zip, then unzip it.

Therefore, you will not be able to simply change the extension of a .xlsx file to .txt or .csv and expect it to be readable in a text editor.  You have to save the file in such a  format form the start.

In Excel, save the spreadsheet as .csv rather than .xlsx, and you can then open it up into a text editor right away!  You can even change the extension to .txt if you really want to.

None of that will work thought, if you don't tell Excel to save itself as plain text rather than as its normal XML structure.

If you are insistent upon supporting .xlsx files, there is a way.  The Office XML File format is an open and public format, allowing you to manipulate it however you like.

You will need to:

1. [Download The Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)
2. [Carefully read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739834.aspx)

In your case, you are probably going to want to access specific cell values, read their contents, then stream them into a new file.

The above documentation provides the following code snippet for accessing Cell values in an Excel document:

```
public static string XLGetCellValue(string fileName, string sheetName, string addressName)
{
   const string worksheetSchema = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
   const string sharedStringSchema = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";

   string cellValue = null;

   //  Retrieve the stream containing the requested
   //  worksheet's info.
   using (SpreadsheetDocument xlDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
   {
      //  Get the main document part (workbook.xml).
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.Load(xlDoc.WorkbookPart.GetStream());

      //  Create a namespace manager, so you can search.
      //  Add a prefix (d) for the default namespace.
      NameTable nt = new NameTable();
      XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
      nsManager.AddNamespace("d", worksheetSchema);
      nsManager.AddNamespace("s", sharedStringSchema);

      string searchString = string.Format("//d:sheet[@name='{0}']", sheetName);
      XmlNode sheetNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(searchString, nsManager);
      if (sheetNode != null)
      {
         //  Get the relId attribute.
          XmlAttribute relationAttribute = sheetNode.Attributes["r:id"];
         if (relationAttribute != null)
         {
            string relId = relationAttribute.Value;
            //  Load the contents of the workbook.
            XmlDocument sheetDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
            sheetDoc.Load(xlDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relId).GetStream());

            XmlNode cellNode = sheetDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//d:sheetData/d:row/d:c[@r='{0}']", addressName), nsManager);
            if (cellNode != null)
            {
               XmlAttribute typeAttr = cellNode.Attributes["t"];
               string cellType = string.Empty;
               if (typeAttr != null)
               {
                  cellType = typeAttr.Value;
               }

               XmlNode valueNode = cellNode.SelectSingleNode("d:v", nsManager);
               if (valueNode != null)
               {
                  cellValue = valueNode.InnerText;
               }
               if (cellType == "b")
               {
                  if (cellValue == "1")
                  {
                     cellValue = "TRUE";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     cellValue = "FALSE";
                  }
               }
               else if (cellType == "s")
               {
                   if (xlDoc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart != null)
                   {
                      XmlDocument stringDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
                      stringDoc.Load(xlDoc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.GetStream());
                      //  Add the string schema to the namespace manager.
                      nsManager.AddNamespace("s", sharedStringSchema);

                      int requestedString = Convert.ToInt32(cellValue);
                      string strSearch = string.Format("//s:sst/s:si[{0}]", requestedString + 1);
                      XmlNode stringNode = stringDoc.SelectSingleNode(strSearch, nsManager);
                      if (stringNode != null)
                      {
                          cellValue = stringNode.InnerText;
                      }
                   }
                }
            }
         }
       }
   }
   return cellValue;
}
```

From there, you can do whatever you like with the cell values =)

Answer (score 2):

You can not save Excel file in text format, You need to use `.csv` extension instead of using  xlsx, or xls, and save it as `.txt`.